# Unexplained Line Gaps when creating Tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm trying to design a diagram with two nodes, with one node below the other node -- fairly simple stuff. What I'm finding however is that for specifically the second node, there's a large newline gap that isn't accounted for in the code. Below is an minimum example and the corresponding compile.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, positioning}
\tikzstyle{blurb}=[rectangle, draw = black, fill = black!10, very thick, rounded corners, align=center, text width = 8em]

\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{title}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [blurb] (foobar) {
\textbf{foobar}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{2em}
\centering
\huge{\faFile*[regular]}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.1em}
\begin{minipage}{5em}
\small{Documents \& Papers}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{2em}
\centering
\huge{\faSearch{}}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.1em}
\begin{minipage}{5em}
\small{Search Queries}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
};
\node [blurb, below = 1em of foobar] (foobar1) {
\textbf{foobar}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{2em}
\centering
\huge{\faFile*[regular]}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.1em}
\begin{minipage}{5em}
\small{Documents \& Papers}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{2em}
\centering
\huge{\faSearch{}}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.1em}
\begin{minipage}{5em}
\small{Search Queries}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Render displaying problem]

As you can see, the two nodes have the exact same code besides positioning, yet the bottom node's `\textbf{Foobar}` has that gap whereas the upper node does not. What the exact line width doesn't matter so much as it should be the same for both nodes. Does anyone have any ideas and/or tips on where to go looking for why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a simplified example below, the "gap" in the first node is smaller than that in other two nodes, and the "gap" seems to represent a lineskip.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\mytext{%
    \begin{center}
      \Huge X
    \end{center}
}

\begin{center}
%  \leavevmode
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw, text width=8em}]
    \node (a) {\mytext};
    \node (b) at (4,0) {\mytext};
    \node (c) at (8,0) {\mytext};
    \foreach \i in {a,b,c}
      \fill[blue] (\i.base) circle (2pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Replacing the `center` environment outside `tikzpicture` with `\centering` solves the problem. Since `center` environment is defined as

```tex
\def\center{\trivlist \centering\item\relax}
\def\endcenter{\endtrivlist}
```

I tried **adding a `\leavevmode` just before `\begin{tikzpicture}`**, and it works, for both my simplified and your original example.

**Besides**, here is an attempt to reconstruct the node contents with `tabular` environment:

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{array}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, positioning}
\tikzstyle{blurb}=[rectangle, draw = black, fill = black!10, very thick, rounded corners, align=center, text width = 8em]

\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{title}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[blurb] (foobar) {%
    \begin{tabular}{@{} >{\huge}l @{\enspace} b{5em} @{}}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{foobar}}     \\
      \faFile*[regular] & Documents \& Papers \\
      \faSearch         & Search Queries      \\
    \end{tabular}%
  };
  \node[blurb, below=1em of foobar] {%
    \begin{tabular}{@{} >{\huge}l @{\enspace} b{5em} @{}}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{foobar}}     \\
      \faFile*[regular] & Documents \& Papers \\
      \faSearch         & Search Queries      \\
    \end{tabular}%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]